# 1985 Putnam A1 Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, analysis, contest-math

[image: jizz]

I dont see what they mean by bijection of triples of subsets of $\{1, \ldots, 10\}$ and the $10\times3$ matrix with $0, 1$ entries?

How is that created?

Comment: You don't need to write $10x3$; you can write $10\times3$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @chi: The map is a bijection between the set of _all_ ordered triples of subsets (without the conditions i and ii), and the set of _all_ binary 10×3 matrices.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are correct. I misread the very first part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example, suppose the three sets are
\begin{align}
A_1 & = \{1,5,6,8\} \\
A_2 & = \{1,2,3,4,10\} \\
A_3 & = \{2,4,5,7,9,10\}
\end{align}
(Note that $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3=\varnothing$.)

Then the $10\times3$ matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The first **column** of the matrix corresponds to the set $A_1$.  It has a $1$ in the $1$st, $5$th, $6$th, and $8$th rows because the members of $A_1$ are $1,5,6,8$.  Similarly the second and third columns correspond respectively to $A_2$ and $A_3$.

Comment: Michael Hardy (+1), at the end though. When they say:

"The number of possibilities of each row of such a matrix is $2^3 - 2 = 6$" what possibility are they talking about? Also, how is it $2^3 - 2$ anyway?

Comment: There are eight $=2^3$ possible rows if you don't require the union of the three sets to contain all ten numbers and also don't require the intersection to be empty.  Those eight are: $(0,0,0),\  (0,0,1),\  (0,1,0),\  (1,0,0),\  (0,1,1),\ (1,0,1),\ (1,1,0),\ (1,1,1)$.  The requirement of non-intersection excludes $(1,1,1)$, and the requirement that all ten numbers be included excludes $(0,0,0)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I got that now =) But I dont understand something. How does the number of the possibilities of the rows of the matrices give the final answer?

Comment: You have six possibilities for the first row, six of the second, six for the third, etc., so you get $\underbrace{{}\,6\cdot6\cdots\cdots6\,{}}_{\text{10 factors}} = 6^{10}$ ways to fill in the blanks. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There are three rows right? 

$$(abc); (abc); (abc)$$

$6$ possibilities for each row?

Comment: Correct. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I dont understand something. $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are all sets right, then how can they be triples are they asking, $x \in A_1$ for example to be the triple? @Michael

Comment: @Amad27 : It is not asserted that they are triples. The sets correspond to $10$-tuples, which are the columns of the matrix. That doesn't mean they are the say thing as $10$-tuples; it just means there is a simple one-to-one correspondence between the subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and the $10$-tuples of members of the set $\{0,1\}$. There is, however, an order triple whose components are the three sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$. And for each member of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ there is an ordered triple indicating which of the three sets it belongs to. Those are the rows of the matrix. ${}\quad$

Comment: I think I have a problem understanding the question. What do they mean when they say:

>"Determine [...] number of ordered triples $(A_1, A_2, A_3)$ of sets" 

What does that statement mean?

Comment: Suppose you have $\{1,2,3,4\}, \{5,6,7\}, \{8,9,10\}$.  That's _one_ ordered triple of sets that fits the bill.  Next, say we have $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, \{4,5,6,7,8,9\}, \{8,9,10\}$.  That's another.  So if we're counting, that two, so far.  Keep going until you have all possibilities.  That's counting the number of ordered triples of sets that satisfy the requirements.  They're asking how many you can get.  And the answer ends up being $6^10$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Any ordered triple whether $A_1, A_2, A_3$ none can have $>10$ elements right? Or else that will create a problem in the union I believe?

Comment: Since their union is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, none of them can have more members than that set has.

Answer (score 16):

For any element $x \in \{1,\ldots,10\}$, in order to satisfy the constraints, $x$ must belong to either exactly 1 or exactly 2 of the sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$. This gives you 6 possibilities per element (why?), for a total of $6^{10}$ possibilities.

Don't bother with the matrix; this is just a fancy way of stating the same argument.

Comment: what have ever the matrices done to you?

Comment: (+1) Great Answer @Yuval. But why only $1$ or $2$ of the sets $A_1, A_2, A_3$ though?

Comment: @Amad27 if an element $x$ belonged to all the sets then we would have $x \in A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @chi, using the matrix idea, they say: "The number of possibilities of each row is $2^3 - 2 = 6$." But which possibilities are they talking bout?

Comment: @Amad27 A generic row may be $(000),(001),(010),\ldots,(110),(111)$ for a total of $2^3$ rows -- yet two of them are impossible, as the book states. So we only get $2^3-2$ admissible rows.

Comment: @chi, So how to do this combinatorically? $(a, b, c)$ and use $2$ for each, giving $2^3$ except, $2$ of them are not possible? **But why does the number of possibilities of the row give the answer**?